# Terraform azurerm_app_service auth_settings new Azure Identity Provider

Tags: azure, terraform, azurerm-app-service

When using the `auth_settings`, this is creating my app service settings within the `Authentication (Classic)` tab. Is there any new way to use terraform to update the `Authentication` tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not supported yet as of azurerm version 2.67.0

One of complain I have is that the application cannot be tested locally, this is the case with Authentication Classic which uses built in authentication of app service(easy auth).

The newer Authentication seems configure the app registration for the popular oauth2 identity providers, but still keep some of client settings on Azure, where it should be kept at web.config.

For this reason I would not use this setting for now, just manually configure the app registration and make configuration in web.config/appsettings.json, and use an authentication library of my pick(MASL that is)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I really do not consider manual configuration an option in my case.

Comment: As the correct implementation is simple and baked into all the quick start VS templates, it is not a bad idea to implement every part  of it and take full control